# API calls are being redirected to root url on Azure with Angular and ASP.NET Core

Tags: angular, azure, api, asp.net-core, redirect

I am working with the new Project Type (part of Visual Studio 2022) Angular with ASP.NET Core backend.

With the app deployed in production, the API call is being redirected to the root page and the index file is being returned.

Example: when I call `https://website.com/_api/controller` it would redirect to `https://website.com` and I would just get the html of the index file.

When running the app in the debugger, everything is working fine only when deployed in production in Azure.

Any idea how to handle this?

Comment: There might be a difference between your environment files. Do you have a BaseURL specified somewhere?

Comment: in the tsconfig.json file the baseURL is empty,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Issue was a Firewall restriction between the Website in Prod and the DB.
The Controller Function was actually throwing an exception and this was redirecting the api call automatically to the root url.